# c++ mysql_query update returns error if content is similar to existing (but no way to differentiate from normal error)

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm trying to set up an error detection system in c++ when doing a mysql_query, to check whether the query failed and if so try again (I'm using the mysql libray for Linux). The function mysql_query returns an int which is set to zero for success, and non-zero if failed (the error numbers are available at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-query.html).

My first problem is that `mysql_query` only returns 0 or 1 for me, and this would be fine until I try to update a database entry with a similar content to what's already in the database. It also returns an error for that, which is fine on the principle, but as I can't differentiate it from an normal error, my current error detection system would try to repeat the query until it stops returning an error, which never happens. You'll tell me I could check what's in the DB first and then compare it to what I try to update before doing the query, and you would be right, but the code is already very complex and adding this level of complexity on the top would take quite some time.

So I'm wondering if there is a simpler answer to that? Thanks

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-errno.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Mat wrote just use `mysql_errno()` (see [Mysql Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-errno.html))

It returns 0 for success or an error code for errors.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for.
It seems my update error actually comes from something else as it returns Error: 2006 (CR_SERVER_GONE_ERROR)

Answer (score 0):

Just so you guys know where this error actually came from, if you ever have the same.

I repetitively had mysql errors 2013 and 2006 when performing queries from different threads at the same time, but only after running a certain number of requests. I tried pretty much everything explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html).

Apparently for some reason the connection crashes and I can't do much to avoid it. The only thing that worked for me is to enable automatic reconnect using `mysql_options` and the option `MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT`. It seems like a work around, more than a real fix, but at least my program doesn't crash now!